# NSGradient on Tiger

Tags: macos, cocoa, gradient, nsview, osx-tiger

I'm creating an app that must run on Tiger and I need to draw a gradient onto a NSView. Unfortunately, NSGradient is only available on Leopard and above. Google wasn't my friend at all. How do I draw a gradient to a NSView on Mac OS X 10.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of developers used [`CTGradient`](http://svn.oofn.net/#CTGradient) before Apple introduced `NSGradient`. It's a wrapper around the `CGShading` C API.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [`CGShading`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGShading/Reference/reference.html) object to draw the gradient, and write the interpolation function for it yourself (an example is given in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-SW5)).